# SQL syntax error: near “.”?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I try to run this query:

```
UPDATE Line_Master 
SET Line_Master.line_count = t2.task_count FROM (SELECT COUNT (am.line_id) AS task_count, lm.lineId
   FROM Assets_Master am,Line_Master lm,Section_Master sm,Task_Point_Master tpm,Task_Master TM
   WHERE (lm.line_id = am.line_id)
     AND (am.asset_id = sm.asset_id)
     AND (sm.section_id = tpm.section_id)
     AND (tm.task_point_id = tpm.task_point_id)
   GROUP BY lm.line_id) t2
WHERE Line_Master.line_id = t2.lineId
```

I get this error:

Internal Error
syntax error: near ".":Syntax error

Comment: post error log with question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but this way the Syntax is correct. But i don't know if it shows your desired result and if sqlite supports this...

```
UPDATE Line_Master 
SET Line_Master.line_count = (SELECT t2.task_count FROM (SELECT COUNT (am.line_id) AS task_count, lm.lineId
   FROM Assets_Master am,Line_Master lm,Section_Master sm,Task_Point_Master tpm,Task_Master TM
   WHERE (lm.line_id = am.line_id)
     AND (am.asset_id = sm.asset_id)
     AND (sm.section_id = tpm.section_id)
     AND (tm.task_point_id = tpm.task_point_id)
   GROUP BY lm.line_id) t2
   WHERE Line_Master.line_id = t2.lineId)
```